# Android Studio DrawerLayout scrimcolor not showing

Tags: android-studio, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, navigationview

I have an activity that uses the following layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/root_main_activity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:openDrawer="start"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout_main_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout_main_activity"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_main_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWindowBackground"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWindowBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/drawer_header" />

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/expandablelistview_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:groupIndicator="@null"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

I have tried all that I could think of, such as; putting the navigationView inside the appbarlayout in different places, putting it before the appbarlayout and after it and lastly trying to set the scrimcolor dynamically in the oncreate method of the activity. None of these things worked, does someone know the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying I made it working. The reason why is not clear to me but here is the working layout for the people who have the same problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_main_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_main_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout_main_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout_main_activity"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_main_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWindowBackground"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWindowBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/drawer_header" />

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/expandablelistview_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:groupIndicator="@null"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```